# Executing procedure in @Scheduled leaves open connection

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have web application peridicly syncing data with calling stored procedure. I don't wont execute procedure in transaction.

After each procedure call entity manager didn't close and leaves connection in connection pool until pool reach max connections and application hangs.

`SharedEntityManagerCreator` creates `EntityManager` and did't close it after import method call because repository executes "execute" method on query but `SharedEntityManagerCreator` specifies only

```
    queryTerminationMethods.add("getResultList");
    queryTerminationMethods.add("getSingleResult");
    queryTerminationMethods.add("executeUpdate");
```

Is this a bug or i am using it wrong?

Here is my service

```
@Service("importService")
@Slf4j
public class ImportService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public ImportService() {
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "${import.cron.pattern}")
    public void importData() {
        userRepository.ImportUserProcedure();        
    }

}
```

and repository calling stored procedure

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<AuthUser, Integer> {

    @Procedure(procedureName = User.ImportUserProcedure)
    void ImportUserProcedure();
}
```

Comment: Your service should be `@Transactional`.

Comment: but if i call ImportUserProcedure from test rest enpoint connections get released

Comment: Because those are generally transactional by default (depending on your setup) or the context is closed closing all connections.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and was glad to find this post for a quick answer. As pointed out in the comments add the Transactional annotation to your procedure function and the connections won't leak.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<AuthUser, Integer> {

    @Transactional
    @Procedure(procedureName = User.ImportUserProcedure)
    void ImportUserProcedure();
}
```